# trying to make ping with scapy but heve an error

Tags: python, ping, scapy

```py
from scapy.all import *
TIMEOUT = 2
conf.verb = 0
for ip in range(0, 256):
    packet = IP(dst="192.168.0." + str(ip), ttl=20) / ICMP()
    reply = sr1(packet, timeout=TIMEOUT)
    if reply is not None:
        print(reply.dst, "is online")
    else:
        print("Timeout waiting for %s" % packet[IP].dst)
```

This is the message I get when I run the code:    `packet = IP(dst="192.168.0." + str(ip), ttl=20) / ICMP()`:

```
TypeError: IP() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dst'
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: It works without any error in python 3.10.6 (WSL) and scapy version 2.5.0 on my machine. It may be related to your specific version of python and/or scapy.

Comment: Can you execute `from scapy.all import VERSION ; print(VERSION)` and post the result?